# Scrape different levels of web pages

Tags: r, web-scraping, dataset

I am doing a research on World Bank (WB) projects on developing countries.
To do so, I am scraping their website in order to collect the data I am interested in.

The structure of the webpage I want to scrape is the following:

1. List of countries [the list of all countries in which WB has developed projects](http://projects.worldbank.org/country?lang=en&page=)

   1.1. By clicking on a single country on 1. , one gets the single countries project list (that includes many webpages) [it includes all the projects in a single countries](http://projects.worldbank.org/search?lang=en&searchTerm=&countrycode_exact=3A)  . Of course, here I have included just one page of a single countries, but every country has a number of pages dedicated to this subject

   1.1.1. By clicking on a a single project on 1.1. , [one gets - among the others - the project's overview option](http://projects.worldbank.org/P155642/?lang=en&tab=overview) I am interested in.

In other words, my problem is to find out a way to create a dataframe including all the countries, a complete list of all projects for each country and an overview of any single project.

Yet, this is the code that I have (unsuccessfully) written:

```
WB_links <- "http://projects.worldbank.org/country?lang=en&page=projects"

 WB_proj <- function(x) {

  Sys.sleep(5)
 url <- sprintf("http://projects.worldbank.org/search?lang=en&searchTerm=&countrycode_exact=%s", x)

 html <- read_html(url)

 tibble(title = html_nodes(html, ".grid_20") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE),
     project_url = html_nodes(html, ".grid_20") %>% html_attr("href")) 
    }

 WB_scrape <- map_df(1:5, WB_proj) %>% 
 mutate(study_description = 
       map(project_url, 
           ~read_html(sprintf
     ("http://projects.worldbank.org/search?lang=en&searchTerm=&countrycode_exact=%s", .x)) %>% 
            html_node() %>% 
            html_text()))
```

Any suggestion?

**Note:** I am sorry if this question seems trivial, but I am quite a newbie in R and I haven't found a help on this by looking around (though I could have missed something, of course).

Comment: instead of scraping, would you consider using their data api? check out these links: ----- https://data.worldbank.org/data-catalog/projects-portfolio ----- http://search.worldbank.org/api/projects/all.csv ----- http://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/projects

Comment: @chinsoon12.
Thanks for your reply.
Yes, I could, but there are similar websites not offering that possibility, hence I would use this well-structured website to get how it works and then apply the method to those "minor" sites.